# React login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write login page in react but asynchronous nature of setState makes this rather difficult.

After submit printing out state gives old values set as initial state instead of updating state with form values.

I know that setState is asynchronous and that there is no guarantee that state will get updated, so what are my options here? How can I make sure that submit will get new values?

Is there possibly a better approach than this?

Code below.

```
var Login = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            name: '',
            password: ''
        }
    },

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var msg = {
            name: this.state.name,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        // name and password are not updated
        console.log(msg)
    },

    handleChange: function(value, e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
             <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Form horizontal>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalName">
                            <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={1}>
                                Name
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={3}>
                                <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                            <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={1}>
                                Password
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={3}>
                                <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password')}/>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <Col smOffset={1} sm={3}>
                                <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <Col smOffset={1} sm={3}>
                                <Button type="submit">
                                    Sign in
                                </Button>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </form>
             </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Login;
```

Comment: Can you add a `console.log({ value: e.target.value })` on `handleChange`

Comment: If there is value field in FormControls for name and password it prints out only last letter, otherwise it prints the entire string written so far. Quite puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by replacing your `handleChange` function by:

```
handleChange: function(value, e) {
    this.setState({ [value]: e.target.value })
},
```

Note that I add `[` `]` to specify I want update the value of the `value` variable (`name` or `password`) instead of the string `value` (your code)

**Example**:

```
   var value = "red" 
   var obj1 = {value: "foo"} // {value: "foo"}
   var obj2 = {color: value} // {color: "red"} 
   var obj3 = {[value]: "foo"} // {red: "foo"}
```

Comment: @user3454914 This has nothing to do with asynchronous setState (that happens soon enough that it's never going to be a problem unless you are relying on the new state in the same stack). You are setting "value" in the state, so you would access that with `this.state.value`. Your handleChange function doesn't affect name `name` and `password` props at all.

Comment: Updated to explain

Comment: This is now so painfully obvious. Thank you. Accepting in 3 minutes.